# Size of data being written is increasing by 1 byte for no reason

Tags: c++, file, input, struct, output

I've got a program, which writes information about students into a file.

I checked what is being written into the file, and found that from the 1st to 9th student, the `index` value changes from `01 00 00 00` to `09 00 00 00`, which is, I guess, what is supposed to happen.

The problem is, when I add the 10th student, the program starts behaving weird. When I add the 10th student, there's a weird byte `0D` being written in front of the index value (`0A 00 00 00`). The data size being written is also not 48, which is the value of `sizeof(Student)`, but 49 bytes instead. And on the 25th student, the size becomes 50 bytes.

Because of that, reading the file using `file.read((char*)&student, sizeof(Student))` becomes impossible after the 25th student because I use `if(!student.removed)` to output information (the `removed` flag is being used for removing students), and if I check the `student.removed` value, after the 25th student it's just a random mess and never 0.

```
struct Student
{
    int group;
    int score[3];
    int avg_score;
    int index;
    char surname[21];
    bool removed;
};
```

And here's a function which fills in the file with `i` students. I used it to check for errors on specific student's amount:

```
void RandomAdd(char* nf, int* amount_r)
{
    int j;
    std::cout << "j: ";
    std::cin >> j;
    std::fstream file;
    file.open(nf, std::ofstream::app);
    if (*amount >= 0)
    {
        Student student;
        for (int i = 1; i <= j; i++)
        {
            (*amount_r)++;
            strcpy(student.surname, "1");
            student.group = 1;
            student.score[0] = 0;
            student.score[1] = 1;
            student.score[2] = 2; 
            student.avg_score = (student.score[0] + student.score[1] + student.score[2]) / 3.;
            student.index = *amount_r;
            student.removed = false;
            std::cout << sizeof(student) << " ";
            file.seekg((i - 1) * sizeof(Student), std::ios::beg);
            file.write((char*)&student, sizeof(Student));
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Here's my `main()` function with `RandomAdd` function call:

```
int main()
{
    char nameF[128] = "file.bin";
    int amount_r = 0;
    int input;
    switch(input)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            Add(nameF, &amount_r);
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: You need to open the file in binary mode. Change `file.open(nf, std::ofstream::app);` to `file.open(nf, std::ofstream::app | std::ofstream::binary);`  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/FILE#Binary_and_text_modes

Comment: This is only one of the many many pitfalls that result from dumping struct contents into files. Adopt a (simple) serialization framework and be happy.

Comment: Thank you! It works also for reading data. Now i know what this binary mode for.

Comment: Well damn. I think I'll have a lot of fun with files in the future:) I'm just learning programming, so I guess it's too early for me to learn about C++ serialization frameworks but I'll check it, thanks

Comment: @Miroigrin -- Change `char surname[21];` to `std::string surname;`, and your entire code with the binary file reading/writing falls to pieces.   The only way that binary read/write code remains relevant is if you can guarantee that `Student` will always be trivially-copyable and not ever contain pointers to data.  That guarantee is very hard to keep, given that you are using C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie wish I could use strings, but at the moment we at the college are learning C, and are only allowed to use <iostream> and <fstream> from C++, so I'll have to stick with char arrays, not for long, hopefully.  I can't think of a situation of Student containing not dereferenced pointers, not in my code at least. Why is it hard to guarantee that struct will not contain pointers, especially in C++? And if the code falls to pieces, what would be a better way to input and output data? Sorry for asking too much questions and for potential grammatical mistakes

Comment: *Why is it hard to guarantee that struct will not contain pointers, especially in C++?* -- Because it is very easy to introduce a variable type in the structure that is non trivially copyable.  What if the new requirement is that the surname can be any length?  As to what you should do, the comment above mentions serialization frameworks.